# When is $g(t):=\inf_{s \in (0,t)} f(s)$ differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Under which non-trivial conditions is the function
$$g(t):=\inf_{s \in (0,t)} f(s)$$
differentiable? Would the differentiability of $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be enough?

Where can I find some theory of such functions?

Comment: Differentiability of $f$ is not enough, e.g., $f(s)=s(1-s)$ gives $g(t)=0$ for $t\in[0,1]$ and $g(t)=f(t)$ for $t>1$, but of course $f'(1)\neq 0$ so $g$ is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: Thanks @user10354138. How about a weaker notion of differentiability (like a.e.?)

Comment: $g$ is monotone (non-increasing), so differentiable almost everywhere.